# Alternative to Lattice's GAL and ispGAL chips

Tags: embedded, gal

I took a class last semester about programming with embedded hardware, mainly using GAl chips from Lattice and ABEL to program them. I'd like to continue this for fun outside of the class, but I find things to be cost prohibitive due to the high costs of buying a programmer.

Are there any free or low-cost ways that I can program something similar to a GAL chip? Please don't suggest AVR or PIC chips, as my main project is I want to actually program and build a CPU out of smaller chips.

I've looked into ispGAL chips, but the cables to program them ISP (USB at least) are $150 or more.

Thanks for any help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a Xilinx evaluation board, the education priced ones are pretty cheap. And you're a student!

I'd guess based on the AUD price, of $150 about USD$100 with all the tools.

This is a bit pricey, but the chip is big enough to do a whole computer in gates.
The eval board has ethernet, PS/2, serial, usb and VGA: and they all connect to the gate array!

For *really* cheap,  Slipway ?

http://research.cs.berkeley.edu/project/slipway/

Comment: Well I wasn't looking for something as powerful as an FPGA, more of a PLD type of thing. I know it would be easier to do it with an FPGA, but I actually want the difficulty of the lower level chips... Just not the hundreds of dollars of equipment that goes with them...